how to use lstm with yolov8?
I currently have a YOLOv8 module trained to detect static sign language letters. Now, I'm looking for a method to detect dynamic sign language words. However, YOLO supports individual images, and I'm considering using LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory) but I lack understanding of how it functions or how it integrates with YOLO.
Could you provide me with some initial guidance on how to proceed with this?
